# Print to stdout from osascript/Applescript

Tags: applescript

I have some AppleScript code that I'm executing with `osascript`. This is part of a larger Perl program. I'd like to be able to print to stdout from the AppleScript, then have the Perl script process the output. But I haven't been able to print from within AppleScript. What should I do?

Here's what I've tried:

- `do shell script "echo Foo"`. Does not ouptut Foo.
- [This Google Groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.comp.lang.applescript/browse_thread/thread/d6fd2cd13927d5b3/5cba6813346a1750) does some trickery to open /dev/fd/1. For me, I get an error of "File Macintosh HD:dev:fd:1 wasn't found"

Here's the script I'm running:

```
tell application "Safari"
        set window_list to every window
        repeat with the_window in window_list
                set tab_list to every tab in the_window

                repeat with the_tab in tab_list
                        set the_url to the URL of the_tab
                        -- I'd like to put a print statement here,
                        -- instead of display dialog
                        display dialog the_url
                end repeat
        end repeat
end tell
```

Since `osascript` will automatically print the last value of a program, I could collect the URLs into a list and print that. But then my Perl script would have to parse the list, remove quotes, etc. It seems like it should be more straightforward to just print one URL per line.

Thanks

Comment: AppleScript hello world is this one liner on the Terminal: `osascript -e 'log "hello world!"`' which should print: `hello world!` to stdout.  You can print the contents of builtin variables such as: `log version` which prints something like `1.0`.  The stdout selected depends on the version of the interpreter you use to run it (osascript) and the application context defined in previous lines, Finder, Chrome and Terminal all redirect your log output differently.  To receive command line parameters use `on run argv`.  Get access to the screen with `display dialog`.

Comment: Eric: output from "log ..." executed via osascript goes to standard error, not standard output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you're asking and I don't know Perl, however I think you could make the parsing from perl simple if you collect your urls in a string instead of a list. Each url would be on a separate line of the string. Perl should be able to turn that into an array pretty easily and then do something with it. Something like the below applescript. Of course you can use a different separator in the applescript. I used "return" but it could just as easily be a "comma" or any other character you want. Whatever is easiest for you in perl to change the string to an array.

```
set urlString to ""

tell application "Safari"
    set window_list to every window
    repeat with the_window in window_list
        set tab_list to every tab in the_window

        repeat with the_tab in tab_list
            set the_url to the URL of the_tab
            set urlString to urlString & the_url & return
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell

return text 1 thru -2 of urlString
```

Comment: Thanks, that will make things easier to parse. The output would basically be the same as if I had printed. But I'm going to hold off on accepting that as the answer, in hopes that someone else will know how to print without building up a string.

Comment: Why is it that the only way to get to stdout from from osascript is the final return value?

Answer (score 4):

I found that I can use 'log' to dump results to STDERR,
though I had to use Chrome instead of Safari:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Chrome"
    repeat with w in every window
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            log (get URL of t)
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: This the best answer for me as you can output to other programs from within a loop, good for massive loops.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `log` is OK.

```
MacBookPro:~ zxj5470$ cat demo.scpt 
tell application "Terminal"
    set WindowNum to get window count
    log WindowNum
end tell
MacBookPro:~ zxj5470$ osascript demo.scpt 
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Evan, you were SO close with

```
do shell script "echo Foo"
```

You wrote that it didn't output Foo, but I'm pretty sure it did; however, it went to standard error, which probably got lost.

It went to standard error because that's how osascript set up the file descriptors before it ran the script.

You can just tell the shell to redirect what's currently the standard error stream to instead go to standard output. That would have done what you wanted. Try this:

```
do shell script "echo Foo 2>&1"
```