# Print to Stdout with applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to run an AppleScript script from the terminal, however I can't get it to print anything by calling

```
 osascript myFile.scpt "/path/to/a/file"
```

I'm trying:

```
on run fileName

set unique_songs to paragraphs of (read POSIX file fileName)

repeat with nextLine in unique_songs
    if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
        set song to text item 2 of nextLine
        set artist to text item 3 of nextLine
        set album to text item 4 of nextLine

        set output to ("Song: " & song & " - " & artist & " - " & album)
        copy output to stdout
    end if
end repeat
end run
```

The tab delimited file is formatted something like this:

```
1282622675  Beneath the Balcony Iron & Wine The Sea & the Rhythm    
1282622410  There Goes the Fear Doves   (500) Days of Summer        
1282622204  Go to Sleep. (Little Man Being Erased.) Radiohead   Hail to the Thief
```

Tabs aren't really showing up well on this :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print to stdout from osascript/Applescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766868/print-to-stdout-from-osascript-applescript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its is not very clear HOW you are trying to run it in Terminal.
But I will assume you have saved a applescript text file  with the  `#!/usr/bin/osascript` [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), and 
`chmod`'ed the file to be able to execute it.

Then called the file in Terminal, by just using the path to the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

#Here be the rest of your code ...

set output to ("Song: " & song & " - " & artist & " - " & album)


    do shell script "echo " & quoted form of output
end tell
```

**Update** 2, in response to comments.

If I have a tab delimited text file with the content as:

```
track   Skin Deep   Beady Belle Closer
```

The tabs are set like :
 track****TAB****Skin Deep****TAB****Beady Belle****TAB****Closer

And the script file as:

```
on run fileName

    set unique_songs to paragraphs of (read POSIX file fileName)

    repeat with nextLine in unique_songs
        if length of nextLine is greater than 0 then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
            set song to text item 2 of nextLine
            set artist to text item 3 of nextLine
            set album to text item 4 of nextLine

            set output to ("Song: " & song & " - " & artist & " - " & album)
            do shell script "echo " & quoted form of output
        end if
    end repeat

end run
```

Then in Terminal run:

```
/usr/bin/osascript ~/Documents/testOsa2.scpt ~/Documents/testTab.txt
```

I get back:

```
*Song: Skin Deep - Beady Belle - Closer*
```

Comment: Hm. That doesn't seem to work either. Updated with how I'm running it. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: I see. How about posting more code. Which may help to get a better idea of what you are doing. Because either way of running should produce something. What are you getting back in terminal.

Comment: Yeah so I'm not only getting errors if the script has crashed in the terminal, however when I have it running in the AppleScript Editor, all of the log data comes out. I'll post some more code.

Comment: Also I assume you mean  osascript  "/path/to/myFile.scpt"

Comment: Actually the file is a tab delimitated file so it's a .txt. I don't have issues with getting and reading the file.

Comment: updated the answer. I should have suggested do shell script and echo  first but my log test worked for me with a simple code. But not for this

Comment: Still isn't working. I replaced "copy output to stdout" with "do shell script "echo " & quoted form of output" and it still doesn't print anything

Comment: Can you put up an example of the text in the text file. I will try it on that.

Comment: I've added it. Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Arg ok looks like my terminal or something must be messed up. Thanks for the help

Comment: I had someone else try it on their computer, and it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 20):

When running the AppleScript with `#!/usr/bin/osascript`, you can just return your desired text output with a return statement at the end of your script.

Comment: This is a much simpler approach than spawning a separate shell process just to print the output of another. In the above example, this would look like `return the quoted form of the output` right before the `end run` line.

Comment: this is much much better. Thank you

Comment: But it sure would be nice to be able to just output chunks of text as they are encountered, rather than having to accumulate them all into a big string, and then having to return that big string at the end.

Comment: This also seems to be a way to prevent a newline from being output. (`log` does this; `return` doesn't.)

Answer (score 8):

Figured out this based on the first answer:

```
copy "Hello World!" to stdout
```

Comment: Note that if you do several outputs like this then only the last will be visible.  The solution is to save the strings as you go along (`set FinalString to FinalString & CurrString & "\n"`) and output the concatenated string at the end.