# conver string to urlencode in BASH only for curl

Tags: bash, curl

I am using a shell script that uses applescript and curl.
I am trying to pass my variable from applescript to curl - it works but there are spaces in my variable which causes problems when I try to add the variable to the url.

I looked only and it seems there are only method to do this python, but is there any way to turn my `userInput` string into a urlencoded format using only shell?

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

osascript -e 'set Alloyvar to "Alloy Client Connect"

set myInputs to display dialog Alloyvar default answer "Company & your name" buttons {"Connect", "Cancel"} default button 1 with title "My Dialog" with icon caution
set userInput to text returned of myInputs
do shell script "rm lmimcc.pkg.zip\
rm -r Support-LogMeInRescue.app\
echo "  & userInput"
curl --data \"EntryID=123456789&tracking0=64\" -H \"user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15\" https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx?name=" & userInput"  --output lmimcc.pkg.zip \
open \"/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/archive utility.app\"  lmimcc.pkg.zip\
sleep 3\
pkill -x \"Archive Utility\"\
open Support-LogMeInRescue.app"'
```

Result is something like:

```
if I enter: "Mac test"
the url will come out as: "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx?name=Mac" instead of "https://secure.logmeinrescue.com/Customer/Download.aspx?name=Mac%20test"
```

Comment: Embedding a shell script inside an osascript that's embedded inside a shell script seems a bit unfortunate. Have you considered returning the collected string from the osascript section to the outer shell to be processed there, instead of starting an inner shell?

Comment: (see [print to stdout from osascript/applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766868/print-to-stdout-from-osascript-applescript) discussing how to do the above).

Comment: Oh - yeah. I wasn't thinking and didn't realize I could try to use the variable outside of the applescript and use curl outside of the shell invocation inside apple script. I don't think that will fix the url encode issue but I think that may make cleaner code. I will try it anyway, not also to clean my code but to see if that can help encode the variable.